# NetBeans - <script type="text/ng-template"> highlighting

Tags: netbeans

Is there any way to tell NetBeans to do correct syntax highlighting within the `<script type="text/ng-template"></script>` block? By default there is no highlighting, which may be annoying with long code pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a request for it assigned to a netbeans developer:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=238949

But no solution so far.

Answer (score 4):

There is a trick I use:

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.tpt">' ?>
    --HTML--
<?php echo '</script>' ?>
```

This makes the NetBeans recognize the HTML inside block.